# Houzz api not working with curl getting NULL response

Tags: java, php, asp.net, web-services, curl

Hello I am working on houzz api i am getting response in postman but using curl i am not getting any response getting blank page. here is the code:-

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
 'X-HOUZZ-API-SSL-TOKEN: dfgs4g65sd4fg654a54rfg65df4g654a1',
 'X-HOUZZ-API-USER-NAME: web_test', 
 'X-HOUZZ-API-APP-NAME: web_test');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.houzz.com/api?format=xml&method=getListing&ProductId=285599"); # URL to post to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); # return into a variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); # custom headers, see above
$result = curl_exec( $ch ); # run!
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

when check the same thing in postman i got these result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetListingResponse>
    <Ack>Error</Ack>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <ErrorCode>25001</ErrorCode>
            <ShortMessage>No Listing Found</ShortMessage>
            <LongMessage>No listing was found with the given SKU or Product ID.</LongMessage>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
</GetListingResponse>
```

I have also tried with  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`

Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much experience in houzz api integration but your `X-HOUZZ-API-SSL-TOKEN` should look something like this `fQABSAASACJHWADVGkK+2nYxxxxxxxxxxxxxERsq2foiU1+zAAMixxxxxxxxxxxxxJabw==`
and try removing `ProductId` parameter from the request.